# Amazon Product API for python - A strange error that I can't figure out

Tags: python, api, product, amazon-product-api

Here is the situation, I'm trying to get this API to work for me, but I can't seem to figure out all of its quirks.  Even when I run the example below (taken from https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src/2b6b628300c4/examples/all-galileo-titles.py) I get random errors.  Now I'm getting an error that says the `__init__()` takes 4 arguments, and I'm only feeding it two.  I put all of the credentials in the correct place, though, and I can't find anywhere in the modules where `__init__()` is demanding extra arguments.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Here is what I was running. More details about the program can be found at that link above.

```
from amazonproduct.api import API
import lxml

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Don't forget to create file ~/.amazon-product-api
    # with your credentials (see docs for details)
    api = API(locale = 'uk')

    result = api.item_search('Books', Publisher= 'RosettaBooks',
        ResponseGroup='Large')

    # extract paging information
    total_results = result.results
    total_pages = len(result)  # or result.pages

    for book in result:

        print 'page %d of %d' % (result.current, total_pages)

        #~ from lxml import etree
        #~ print etree.tostring(book, pretty_print=True)

        print book.ASIN,
        print unicode(book.ItemAttributes.Author), ':',
        print unicode(book.ItemAttributes.Title),
        if hasattr(book.ItemAttributes, 'ListPrice'):
            print unicode(book.ItemAttributes.ListPrice.FormattedPrice)
        elif hasattr(book.OfferSummary, 'LowestUsedPrice'):
            print u'(used from %s)' % book.OfferSummary.LowestUsedPrice.FormattedPrice
```

Comment: You should show the *actual* error *and* the traceback. All that information is vital for debugging. (Which `__init__`, for example?)

Comment: Good point!  Here it is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unrankedcall.py", line 8, in <module>
    api = API(locale = 'uk')
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I found on the bitbucket site for python-amazon-product-api a question from a couple of years ago that enabled me to work around the problem.  See [11/1/2011 new requirement AssociateTag -- update required?](https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/issue/29/11-1-2011-new-requirement-associatetag)

What I did to work around is not use the .amazon-product-api file to specify the credentials but instead pass them as part of the API call:

```
AWS_KEY = '……….'
SECRET_KEY = '……………'
ASSOCIATE_TAG = '…………….'
api = API(access_key_id=AWS_KEY, secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, locale="us", associate_tag=ASSOCIATE_TAG)
```